# Installation of CINSimulator- Berlin and the result of make is install- recursive error 1

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

My problem occurred while I was installing CINSim- this is a multistage network simulator designed by TU-Berlin. My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and up to this point I have managed to complete the installation steps given in the CINSim handbook.

After successful `./configure` came the `make` command. Its result is shown in the image.

The handbook states

> This simulator requires "version 2.4 of Xerces-C++, but versions up to 2.7.0 were tested with CINSim

I installed version 3.2.1 which is the latest one available, but somehow there are undefined references to xercecs 2-7. I made the effort to install 2.7 version as well, but there were building errors so I just left it that way- with the latest one. The folders of the simulator and xercecs-3.2.1 are in the same directory which is home.

[image: error message]

Comment: Please provide a link to the software page. Which version of the software are you trying to build, which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: This is the original site of TU-Berlin.   https://www.lfa.uni-wuppertal.de/?id=2187&data=29  Files that I downloaded are cinsim-gui-06.tar 02.gz and cinsim-0.6.3.tar.gz.       In sections  the cinsim handbook is provided:    https://www.lfa.uni-wuppertal.de/fileadmin/_migrated/content_uploads/cinsim_handbook_v0.6.pdf      About Xercecs-3.2.1 I followed the building steps for UNIX/Linux using commands ./configure, make, make install.    http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html

Comment: »» This simulator requires "version 2.4 of Xerces-C++ «« → Xerces-c **2.xx** : `sudo apt install libxerces-c2-dev`

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libdevel/libxerces-c2-dev                      I downloaded this package and followed the instructions from Read me file:  file:///home/radostina/Downloads/NEW/xerces-c-src_2_8_0/doc/html/build-winunix.html#UNIX The result is still the same. I removed xerces 3.2.1 folder. Maybe I will try to install 2.7 version but 2.8 is  it not the same... Both cinsim and xerces are in home directory.

Answer (score 0):

`cinsim-0.6.3` : `sudo apt install libxerces-c2-dev bison++ libgsl0-dev`

Some difficulties building cinsim with Ubuntu 16.04 : Old files (year 2010) require e.g. gcc version 4.4, and worse: The `mpic++` compiler must be built with the g++-4.4 compiler. I.e. the Ubuntu 16.04 mpic++ version is a late build. (Built with g++ version 5.4.0).

The easy way : Build the application on Ubuntu 10.04 . (Did so three years ago : Result = cinsim_0.6.3-ubuntu10.4_i386.deb).

**64bit** cinsim : `cinsim_0.6.3-ubuntu10_amd64.deb`, 11.6MB (A new build, the cinsim-gui files are included) → https://drive.google.com/file/d/125_rvVbVFJ89E6JRz6aCBOh9hjjaJ3su/view?usp=sharing

Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64 → Download, and install:

```
cd Downloads/
sudo gdebi cinsim_0.6.3-ubuntu10_amd64.deb
```

Installs OK with Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64. `$ cinsim` : OK too.

Comment: Thank all of you for the help! I will give back answer in a short time.

Comment: I tried the last command and you can see the response here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K0h-57EUIrS3LIVNLs6cm763zfiYauD4/view?usp=sharing ; I downloaded libgsl0ldbl_1.16+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb file and tried to install it similar way like cinsim but there is a conflict between the packages. Then I tried to remove  libgsl2 libgsl2:i386 but there is no difference.

Comment: Please never show text as an image. I guess you know how to copy-paste a text to a file / to a new empty file / to this site. ... About `libgsl0ldbl` : OK, I just realized that i have a couple of "trusty" lines in /etc/apt/sources.list : trusty main universe , trusty-updates main universe . (I have ~60 'Linux OS' installed for applications build / test. So I just forgot how this Ubuntu 16.04 was set up.)